# MASM: stepping through my code, and my start never runs

Tags: debugging, assembly, breakpoints, masm

I cant seem to get basic things running in MASM, I try to step through my code to watch eax change with each command, and I never get to my code. (please ignore the additional includes, I am just testing things.) Appreciate any help or tutorials,
heres my masm code:

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT, stdcall
option casemap :none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
.DATA 

.CODE             

start:
    mov eax,  2DF3Fh    
    mov eax, 3122h
    mov  eax, 1101101b
    mov eax, 434789
    mov eax, 4EFA1101h
    mov eax, 2675411o
end start
PUBLIC start
END
```

Comment: Try changing `END` to `END start`.

Comment: If it never gets to your code, what are you stepping through?  How do you know you just haven't stepped long enough?

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint on your first instruction labeled `start:` and run the program to see if it hits?